# How to disable hosts: all in Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I would like to disable `hosts: all` in the Ansible inventory file.
Sometimes people forget modify the hosts column in YAML file so they  push new configuration to all hosts in the intranet accidentally.

I am very new to Ansible, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by ``disable hosts: all``? What should happen when you run a playbook where ``hosts: all``?

Comment: @VladimirBotka It doesn't matter what should happen, exit code 1 or some error message is fine.  I just don't want people to use hosts: all in their playbook. But seems like it is impossible:)

Comment: Sure it isn't. From the IT perspective :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to keep `hosts: all` in all playbooks and want to limit the hosts in the runtime by the option `--limit`. Next, you want to prevent running the playbooks without limitation at all hosts.

Q: How to disable hosts: all in Ansible?

A: There is no such option in Ansible that would disable the group *all*. The group *all* is created automatically and comprises all hosts in the inventory.

Instead, in the playbook, you can test whether the playbook targets all hosts or not, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: ansible_play_hosts_all|length < groups.all|length
        fail_msg: '[ERROR] All hosts not allowed.'
      run_once: true
```

the play will not continue without the limitation of the hosts

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

...

TASK [assert] **************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: ansible_play_hosts_all|length < groups.all|length
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: '[ERROR] All hosts not allowed.'
```

---

**Implementation**

You don't have to modify all playbooks. Instead, create wrappers. For example, given the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook-509.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: playbook-509 is running ...
```

create the wrapper

```yaml
shell> cat playbook-509-wrapper.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: ansible_play_hosts_all|length < groups.all|length
        fail_msg: '[ERROR] All hosts not allowed.'
      run_once: true

- import_playbook: playbook-509.yml
```

Allow the users to run the wrappers only. For example, the play won't run if a user runs the wrapper without limitation

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-509-wrapper.yml

...

TASK [assert] ***************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: ansible_play_hosts_all|length < groups.all|length
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: '[ERROR] All hosts not allowed.'
```

The play will run if the hosts are limited

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-509-wrapper.yml --limit host01

PLAY [all] *****************************************************

TASK [assert] **************************************************
ok: [host01] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY [all] *****************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  msg: playbook-509 is running ...
```

You can use Ansible to create the wrappers automatically.

Comment: Tried your solution. It's more complicated than I thought but it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The only host that can kind-of-exist and not be part of the `all` group is [implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html); any other host is automatically part of `all`, even if you don't explicitly list it as a parent group.